# Get error details to the client

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am having a problem getting model state details to the client. I have some code like this:

```
var error = new HttpError(modelStateDictionary, true);
throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, error));
```

modelStateDictionary is the model state containing the error details. 
Locally it works great. The modelState gets returned as JSON and via backbone I can show error details to the user. But live it simply returns "Bad Request" - and not even in JSON.

Why is that? I am even including the boolean flag to include error details in the HttpError costructor.